# Picasso not showing images with custom link Android

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I have been working with Picasso recently and trying to display an image to  an ImageView. If I put a normal image link it works, but my problem is that I need to create a custom image link to display on my imageview. This is because I have to retrieve the images a specific user has uploaded, and to do so, I am creating a final String variable to create my link.

Here it is:

```
int a = 1;
    final String imageLink = "http://www.mywebsite.com/pictures/" + username_ + "/" + username_ + a +".jpg";

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageLink).into(ivImagenes);
    tvFotoid.setText("Foto: "+ a);

    bPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (g.getA() != 5 ){
                g.setA(g.getA()+1);
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay más imágenes.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageLink).into(ivImagenes);
            tvFotoid.setText("Foto: "+ g.getA());
        }
    });

    bMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (g.getA() != 1 ){
                g.setA(g.getA()-1);
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay más imágenes.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageLink).into(ivImagenes);
            tvFotoid.setText("Foto: "+ g.getA());
        }
    });
```

Basically every user has 5 pictures and a + and - button will go through them. I have to retrieve the image depending on every user´s username.

So the final link would be www.mywebsite.com/pictures/username/username1.jpg or /username2.jpg, etc.

If I put this as the link directly it works, but it would only show one user´s photos.

Please help, any help is enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `final` seems incorrect here.
Try this:

```
updateImage(username_, 1);

bPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (g.getA() != 5 ){
            g.setA(g.getA()+1);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay más imágenes.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        updateImage(username_, g.getA());
    }
});

bMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (g.getA() != 1 ){
            g.setA(g.getA()-1);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay más imágenes.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        updateImage(username_, g.getA());
    }
});


private void updateImage(String username, int index) {
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(getImageLink(username, index)).into(ivImagenes);
    tvFotoid.setText("Foto: "+ index);
}

private String getImageLink(String username, int index) {
    return "http://www.mywebsite.com/pictures/" + username + "/" + username + a + ".jpg"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! will test now